# Lucene with zoie, can not overwrite index file

Tags: lucene

I am using the bobo browse API. It supports zoie for real time indexing. Zoie internally using the lucene.  I am trying to create index but came across following error. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

```
Zoie verison 3.0.0.
Lucene 2.9.2
OS : windows 7 64bit

26 Jan 2013 20:50:34,352 ERROR proj.zoie.impl.indexing.internal.RealtimeIndexDataLoader@39bc2399 proj.zoie.impl.indexing.internal.LuceneIndexDataLoader - Problem copying segments: Cannot overwrite: C:\D-Drive\ProfilerNewJourney\releases\AbbottRegulatory\FacetIndexFinal\event\_2.fdt
java.io.IOException: Cannot overwrite: C:\D-Drive\releases\FacetIndex\_2.fdt
    at org.apache.lucene.store.FSDirectory.initOutput(FSDirectory.java:362)
    at org.apache.lucene.store.SimpleFSDirectory.createOutput(SimpleFSDirectory.java:58)
    at org.apache.lucene.index.FieldsWriter.<init>(FieldsWriter.java:61)
    at org.apache.lucene.index.SegmentMerger.mergeFields(SegmentMerger.java:334)
    at org.apache.lucene.index.SegmentMerger.merge(SegmentMerger.java:153)
    at org.apache.lucene.index.IndexWriter.mergeMiddle(IndexWriter.java:5045)
    at org.apache.lucene.index.IndexWriter.merge(IndexWriter.java:4630)
    at org.apache.lucene.index.IndexWriter.resolveExternalSegments(IndexWriter.java:3809)
    at org.apache.lucene.index.IndexWriter.addIndexesNoOptimize(IndexWriter.java:3718)
    at proj.zoie.impl.indexing.internal.BaseSearchIndex.loadFromIndex(BaseSearchIndex.java:234)
    at proj.zoie.impl.indexing.internal.LuceneIndexDataLoader.loadFromIndex(LuceneIndexDataLoader.java:212)
    at proj.zoie.impl.indexing.internal.DiskLuceneIndexDataLoader.loadFromIndex(DiskLuceneIndexDataLoader.java:138)
    at proj.zoie.impl.indexing.internal.RealtimeIndexDataLoader.processBatch(RealtimeIndexDataLoader.java:177)
    at proj.zoie.impl.indexing.internal.BatchedIndexDataLoader$LoaderThread.run(BatchedIndexDataLoader.java:380)
```

Comment: Issue is resolved. File handlers are opened by ZoieSystem. so restarting zoie system resolved the issue. More on this thread https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/zoie/QmYd5-QRXMk

Answer (score 0):

Issue is resolved. File handlers are opened by ZoieSystem. so restarting zoie system resolved the issue. More on this thread groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/zoie/QmYd5-QRXMk – Rocky